# Couldn't find index page for 'flickrapi' (maybe misspelled?)

Tags: python, git, pip, installation

I am working on installing the flickr-views-counter package. I want to use this as a codebase for developing a more robust set of flickr routines for a CLI application.

I can install it properly using

```
pip install flickr-views-counter
```

But when I clone it from git, and then use setup, I get

```
Searching for flickrapi
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/flickrapi/
Couldn't find index page for 'flickrapi' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
```

To wit -

```
python setup.py build 
running build 
running build_py
```

followed by -

```
sudo python setup.py install
Password:
running install
Checking .pth file support in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
/usr/bin/python -E -c pass
TEST PASSED: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ appears to support .pth files
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
...
Installing flickr-views-counter script to /usr/local/bin

Installed /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flickr_views_counter-0.1.0-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for flickr-views-counter==0.1.0
Searching for flickrapi
**Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/flickrapi/
Couldn't find index page for 'flickrapi' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for flickrapi
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('flickrapi')**
```

requirements.txt has only the string 'flickrapi' in it.

The page https://pypi.python.org/simple/flickrapi/ contains dozens of zipped flickrapi tar files and egg files.

Do I need to use a specific version of flickrapi for this to work?
What is the index page it is looking for?

Thanks for any help in this. flickrapi is installed fine w/ the pip install, but not through setup. Still confused as to how this is working.

Comment: 1. Are you behind a proxy? Check if e.g. `curl https://pypi.python.org/simple/flickrapi` works. 2. Do you have a file `~/.pydistutils.cfg` available? If yes, post what's in it.

Comment: (1) no response, just a quick return and exit, exit code=0 
(2) I do not have that file.

Comment: Oh, that's because there's a redirect - can you try `curl -L https://pypi.python.org/simple/flickrapi`? You should get the HTML with the list of different package versions.

Comment: A lot there! 54 lines total, all the different versions of flickrapi from 0.15 up through 2.4.0, and a mix of zips, eggs, and whls.